# opencv, emgucv with vb.net. Need help

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, opencv, emgucv

I have some troubles to understand all this. I downloaded and installed egmucv and opencv then i builded emgucv solution and copied dll's to my project then added them as reference and imported them in my project now when i run some emgu example or try to write a code for example a camera tutorial on emgu site and when i run a project it throws me error *(The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.)* anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

i have windows 7 x64 and vs 2010

Can someone gude me to understand how to use this libraries?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of emgucv have you installed? 
I have your same machine configuration and have no issues with emgucv.

The most probable thing you missed is to install 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64).

Comment: sorry i forgot to write here. i did it now it works, it was problem with build i have builded wrong i builded emgu for x64 and my project for x86... now i solved it by rebuilding all for x86. you can write this as an answer then i will accept you as answer. and if you have time you may add me on skype i have some other problem i mean if you have much experiance with this opencv and emgucv skype "fertoll" just few questions. thanks